# Setting dir="rtl" in <html> tag doesn't seem to work, works in <h:body>

Tags: jsf, facelets, right-to-left, dir

I want to write the text of a JSF with dir="rtl" (Right To Left) when a condition is satisfied. I have checked in a HTML file that if you write in the html tag dir="rtl", like this:

```
<html dir=rtl">
```

All the pages tags are set dir="rtl", without having to write dir="rtl" in each tag.

But when I write in my XTHML file the following code, and the condition is false but it does not work, the pages tags are NOT set dir="rtl".

```
<html  
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    dir="#{languageSwitcher.dirWriting() == true ? 'ltr' : 'rtl'}">
```

At first I thought that it could be because html tag can not accept EL (Expression Language) so I tried to write the following code to check if it worked, but again I had the same, problem the pages tags are NOT set dir="rtl", so I guess that html tag not accepting EL is not the problem.

```
<html  
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    dir="rtl">
```

Instead if I write in the body tag:

```
<h:body  dir="#{languageSwitcher.dirWriting() == true ? 'ltr' : 'rtl'}">
```

It works

Why if I write it in the html tag it does not work?

**UPDATE:**

When I view the html code with my browser (View source code) this is what I see:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
```

If I view it using Firebug this is what I see:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Comment: Works just fine for me. When I do *View Source* in browser, the `<html dir="rtl">` is there. Do you mean to say that it's absent for you? Or that it is actually present, but doesn't seem to have any effect? Which JSF impl/version are you using?

Comment: It is absent the <html dir="rtl" > tag when I view the souce code in my Firefox browser. In fact the <html> tag is absent. I think I am using JSF 2.2 at least that is what faces-config.xml says

Comment: Absent? That's awkward. Either the template is wrong or there's a bug I've not seen before. Which JSF impl/version? Can you post smallest possible full XHTML file which reproduces this issue? Perhaps you're incorrectly wrapping an `<ui:composition>` in it or so? Also that XML prolog actually doesn't belong there. In any case, you can find here kickoff (full!) examples of proper templates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets