# JSF page with internationalization - javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'index' resolved to null

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I want to implement simple JSF page based on this [tutorial](http://jdevelopment.nl/internationalization-jsf-utf8-encoded-properties-files/) with JSF 2.2

**faces-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
            http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
              version="2.2">
    <application>
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>en</default-locale>
            <supported-locale>es</supported-locale>
        </locale-config>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>com.web.common.internationalization.text</base-name>
            <var>text</var>
        </resource-bundle>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

**index.xhtml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html lang="#{index.language}"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <f:view locale="#{index.locale}">
        <h:head>

        </h:head>
        <h:body>

            <h:form>
                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{index.language}" onchange="submit()">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="en" itemLabel="English" />
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="es" itemLabel="Spanish" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>
            </h:form>

            <address class="top-address">
                <span><h:outputText value="#{text['customer.support']}" /></span>&nbsp;
            </address>

        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

**CDI Bean**

```
 import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Locale;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class Index implements Serializable
{
    private Locale locale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale();

    public Locale getLocale()
    {
        return locale;
    }

    public String getLanguage()
    {
        return locale.getLanguage();
    }

    public void setLanguage(String language)
    {
        this.locale = new Locale(language);
    }
}
```

I added here Text Java Class from the tutorial and the properties files.

[image]

But for some reason when I open the web page I get error code 500. Do you have any idea where I'm wrong?

**Error stack:**

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @15,80 value="#{index.language}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'index' resolved to null
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getConvertedValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:95)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.convertSelectOneValue(MenuRenderer.java:201)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.getConvertedValue(MenuRenderer.java:318)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1046)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:976)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1249)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:712)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1195)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'index' resolved to null
```

Comment: You should post your server log related to the error 500

Comment: @perissf: regarding the error yes, regarding the 'solution' not.

Comment: @Kukeltje, as seen from the answer by fdreger and the comment by Peter, both the problem and its solution were identified in my duplicate. The NPE appears to be unrelated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the wrong import - the `@SessionScoped` is from the faces package, it should be the one from the `javax.enterprise.context` package.

Or you can switch `@Named` to `@javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean`, then the @SessionScoped will match (it will no longer be a CDI bean though).

Comment: Referring to the 'duplicate' is an option to ;-) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986847/java-ee-6-javax-annotation-managedbean-vs-javax-inject-named-vs-javax-faces

Comment: Now I get NPE at this line `private Locale locale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale();`

Comment: @Kukeltje: if everyone did it, there would be no StackOverflow as we know it :-)

Comment: I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30653945/facescontextgetviewroot-returns-null-while-setting-fview-locale-for-first For now it solved the problem.

Comment: By the way when I switch the JSF pages into the war package(all other beans are in ViewScope) are these properties going to be preserved?

Comment: @PeterPenzov What do you mean by a "property"? Generally packaging doesn't change anything.

Comment: I mean if I select Spanish on the fist page and I open several other pages and I return back to the fist one is it going to remember that I had selected Spanish?

Comment: As long as the session lasts, yes.